# goBack not working properly in React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

```
const RootNav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Splash: {
        screen:Splash
    },
    BeforeLogin: {
        screen:BeforeLogin
    },    
    Signin: {
        screen:Signin,
    },
    Signup: {
        screen:Signup
    },
    Tabs: {
        screen:TabHolder,
    },
    ForgotPassword: {
        screen:ForgotPassword
    },
  } );
```

I'm using this `componentWillMount` in `BeforeLogin` screen. I want to close the app when user presses the android back button.

```
 componentWillMount() {          // In BeforeLogin Screen
   BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',() => {        
       BackHandler.exitApp(); 
     });  
  }
```

And in `Signup` and `Signin` screen, I'm using the below `componentWillMount`

```
componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',() => {   

      this.props.navigation.goBack();
      return true;

    });
  }
```

I cannot use `this.props.navigation.navigate('BeforeLogin)` because within Signin screen, I've a text **Don't have account? Sign up now** which navigates to Signup screen.

And a **Already have account? Sign in now** on my Signup screen which navigates to Signin Screen.

With all of the code I tried so far, I'm now unable to close the app when I press android back button from `BeforeLogin` screen.

I tried it with `goBack(null) too, it takes me to the`Splash`screen when I press android back button from`BeforeLogin` screen.

********************** Second alternative which also didn't work **********************

I used `this.props.navigation.pop(1);` in `Signup` and `Signin` Screen. It takes me to the `Splash` screen when I press android back button from `BeforeLogin` screen.

Please help.

**UPDATED CODE**

Please check the below link. It's the code to my question.
https://gist.github.com/shubham6996/2c69f5a270d88c710ab61487639bf1af

Comment: you are using componentWillMount on before login page that means when component will get render code inside componentWillMount will run first. so when you click goBack button it doesn't go inside  componentWillMount.

Comment: @LokeshKumarMeena still not working

Comment: Do you know how componentDidUpdate works ???? you need to set a variable in component state and update that on goBack click event so that component gets updated and it finally goes into componentDidUpdate Lifecycle.

Comment: @LokeshKumarMeena I don't think my issue here is with `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: So when you press back button it goes into componentWillMount function???

Comment: Yes. Initially. But when I navigate from `BeforeLogin` to `Signin` or `Signup` screen, and then come back to `BeforeLogin` screen, then my back button doesn't works.

Comment: That's what i am saying `componentWillMount` will execute only once at the start, you need to use `componentDidUpdate` that execute whenever the component get updated.

Comment: @LokeshKumarMeena I used `componentDidUpdate`. Didn't work. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187859/discussion-between-lokesh-kumar-meena-and-shubham-bisht).

Comment: @LokeshKumarMeena can you please check the code. https://gist.github.com/shubham6996/2c69f5a270d88c710ab61487639bf1af

Comment: https://medium.com/building-with-react-native/android-back-button-handling-in-react-native-apps-1x08-e3acb0990011

Try this

Answer (score 0):

In a screen from which you want to close screen afterwards after clicking (i assume in BeforeLogin):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._didFocusSubscription = props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', payload =>
      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPressAndroid)
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._willBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('willBlur', payload =>
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPressAndroid)
    );
  }

  onBackButtonPressAndroid = () => {
BackHandler.exitApp();
return true;
}
```

You cannot rely on regular lifecycles of React in React Navigation due to how stacks navigation works there (in fact they are getting some lifecycles only once as they are still mounted underneth). So basically you need to rely on special events that are being sent by navigation itself.

Comment: I tried  using your solution with `this.props.navigation.pop(1);` and `this.props.navigation.goBack(null);` in `Signin` and `Signup` screen and it navigates to `Splash` Screen

Comment: I do not understand. What do you want to do? I showed youu a solution for closing an app from custom screen e.g. BeforeLogin in your case. And now you comment back about how to go back?

Comment: If you are taken to Splash screen then it measn that it is next ont he stack. You probably replace the BeforeLogin screen or reset it. I do not see your code nor navigation and how oyu navigate around.

Comment: Yes, Splash Screen is in the stack. But when I press back button from `BeforeLogin`, I want the app to be closed. But not to be navigated to Splash Screen

Comment: Then you add the code that i inserted above in BeforeLogin screen

Comment: Yes i tried you code. It takes me to the Splash Screen

Comment: Please check my code. https://gist.github.com/shubham6996/2c69f5a270d88c710ab61487639bf1af

Comment: also add to onBackButton return true (like in edit answer right now)

Comment: my back button on `BeforeLogin` is not working when I navigate to `Signin` or `Signup` screen and come back to `BeforeLogin` screen